# Как занести выбраного Героя в базу данных :

Tags: php

```
    <input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='1' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#001 Bulbasaur</b> - Травяной Ядовитый<br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/001.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='4' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#004 Charmander</b> - Огненный <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/004.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='7' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#007 Squirtle</b> - Водный <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/007.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='152' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#152 Chikorita</b> - Травяной <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/152.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='155' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#155 Cyndaquil</b> - Огненный <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/155.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='158' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#158 Totodile</b> - Водный <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/158.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='252' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#252 Treecko</b> - Травяной <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/252.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='255' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#255 Torchic</b> - Огненный <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/255.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='258' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>#258 Mudkip</b> - Водный <br><img src=img/pkmn/normal/258.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1>

Суть вопроса в названии!
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вытащите имя героя `regexp'ом` типа (`<b>.*</b>`), уберите первые 5 символов и занесите в базу данных. Остальные данные парсятся точно также.

Вообще, конечно, за **парсинг `html` кода регулярными выражениями** нужно отрывать руки, но, думаю, в данном случае это приемлемо.

*Боюсь, что подробнее ответить на этот вопрос будет сложно.*

Comment: Вы попробуйте =) Я в этом не очень силен и вот прошу объяснить =)

Comment: @Prikol Ну я пробовать точно не собираюсь, но если вы напишете, что именно по каждому герою вы хотели бы записать в базу данных, и что у вас **не получилось**, то, возможно, смогу помочь.

Comment: Смотрите:
В бд Жизни , атака и т.п. для покемона выставляется сразу, тоисть мне нужно занести только имя покемона и его картинку(ссылку)! Вот это у меня и не получается Я делаю так:
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error());//Заносим пользователя

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (name_poke) values('$name_poke')") or die(mysql_error());//создаем покемона игрока

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `inventar` () values()") or die(mysql_error());//создаем инвентарь игрока

Comment: А занести имя и картинку(ссылку) нужно занести того покемона которого выбрал пользователь. какие нужно переменные и т.п. использовать ? Подскажите пожалуйста =)

Comment: @Prikol Так, ну, [**во-первых.**][1]

  [1]: http://lurkmore.ru/images/5/53/11318-131945-5c812c9bc8c08b83a416dccd875eac53.jpg

Comment: @Prikol А во вторых, у вас есть база этих ваших самых покемонов. **У каждой записи в базе есть поля - hp, атака, имя, картинка.** Также у каждого покемона есть некоторый `id`, по которому вы можете сопоставить уже имеющиеся данные и новые *(имя, картинка)*. Все, что вам нужно сделать - это провернуть запрос типа `UPDATE pokemon SET pokemon.name = name, pokemon.image = image WHERE pokemon.id = id`.

Comment: Теперь <a href="http://lurkmore.ru.nyud.net/images/5/53/11318-131945-5c812c9bc8c08b83a416dccd875eac53.jpg"><B>Я</B></a>
Объясните пожалуйста подробнее =)